# Request suddenly requires the Admin SDK API--didn't before?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-console-developer, google-admin-settings-api

My organization has a project that in the past has been able to function without issue with just the Google Drive and Google Picker APIs. Recently, (within the last few weeks?) I now get 403 errors that enabling the **Admin SDK API** is required.

> *Admin SDK has not been used in project XXXXXX before or is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/admin.googleapis.com/overview then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.*

The project *does* make a request to the admin api (https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/admin/directory_v1/rest) along with its request to the drive api, *but* it's been doing that for years without needing to enable the Admin SDK API, and we've made no code changes there. Did something change recently around when the Admin SDK API is required?

(The project does have a service account, domain-wide delegation is enabled, etc.)

Comment: ¿No scopes changed?

Comment: No scopes changed. The service account client has always been authorized just for the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

Comment: Are you using a client library or just the rest endpoint?

Comment: Could you please provide the code related to the Admin SDK request your project is doing? If you're doing a request to one of its endpoints, you certainly need to have to enable this API.